# Compilation with EMMA fails

Tags: java, maven, report, code-coverage, emma

I want to add emma reports into the maven project I have configured the plugin in pom :

```
<plugins>     
  <plugin>      
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>emma-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-alpha-3</version>
    <inherited>true</inherited>          
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>process-classes</phase>               
        <goals>
          <goal>instrument</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <inherited>true</inherited>
    <configuration>
      <forkMode>once</forkMode>
      <reportFormat>xml</reportFormat>
      <classesDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-classes/emma/classes</classesDirectory>    
    </configuration>        
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

and when I run 
    mvn clean install

I get following error

```
[INFO] Compiling 58 source files to target/test-classes
 INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
 [ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
 [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
 [ERROR]  src/test/java/project/testframework/junit/support/SupportInvoker.java:[80,21] cannot access org.springframework.core.env.EnvironmentCapable
 class file for org.springframework.core.env.EnvironmentCapable not found
                                    supports.add(ctx.getBean(support));
 [ERROR] src/test/java/project/testframework/mockwebcontext/MockWebApplicationContextLoader.java:[37,72] cannot access org.springframework.beans.factory.Aware
 class file for org.springframework.beans.factory.Aware not found
                            final DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet = new DispatcherServlet() {
 [ERROR] src/test/java/project/testframework/mockwebcontext/MockWebApplicationContextLoader.java:[38,24] method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
```

When I run mvn clean install without emma everything works without any errors.
I can run emma using eclipse plugin and it works as well but I can't get emma work from maven.

Any Ideas ??